# How to set state from multiple Select components in one method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got two select components and I want to set values from this selectors to state using one handleChange method. I've tried to do like this:

```
handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    if (name === 'City') {
        this.setState({ selectedCity: value });
    } else if (name === 'Theatre') {
        this.setState({ selectedTheatre: value });
    }
};
```

But I want more universal solution, like I did with inputs:

```
handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
};
```

My state

```
this.state = {
    cities: [],
    theatres: [],
    movies: [],
    selectedCity: 1,
    selectedTheatre: 1
};
```

Comment: Does my solution help? Is there any other issue you are encountering while attempting to create a reusable handleChange function?

Answer (score 0):

at the first, the name for each input must look like the element in the state
ex

tell me

```
handaleChange=(event)=>{
this.setState({
[event.name]=event.target.value
}
```

}

tell me if it work or not

Comment: handaleChange with inputs works well, i've got issue with select elements

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your dropdown list name matches the state name

```
this.state = {
      cities: [],
      theatres: [],
      movies: [],
      selectedCity: 1,
      selectedTheatre: 1
    };

<select name="selectedCity" 
   value={this.state.selectedCity} 
   onChange={this.handleChange }>
</select>


 <select 
   name="selectedTheatre" 
   value={this.state.selectedTheatre} 
   onChange={this.handleChange }>
 </select>


  handleChange = event => {
    const target = event.target
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value
    const name = target.name

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };
```

Note: Dont forget to copy your event data into a variable or call event.persist() to avoid issues. 
See link  [[Event target is null inside functional setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708518/event-target-is-null-inside-functional-setstate])

Answer (score 0):

make Handel different for selected Combobox  element different

```
    handelSelectedElement=(event)=>{
 const value=event.target.checked
 const name:event.target.name;
let cityselected=Object.assign({},this.state.city,{[name]:value})
this.setState({city:cityselected})}
```

tell me if work or not