# Material Design React Multiple Select Placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I'm trying to make my React component behave like the example for Placeholder in Multiple Select [here](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select).

However, after many variations of the code, I can't seem to put the placeholder value there as the default value like in their code.

Here's my code:

```
const units = [
    'box',
    'pieces',
    'ounces'
];

export default function MultipleSelect() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    units: ''
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControl className={clsx(classes.formControl, classes.noLabel)}>
                <Select
                    value={values.units}
                    onChange={handleChange('units')}
                    autoWidth
                    renderValue={selected => {
                        console.log(selected);
                        if (!selected) return "Placeholder";
                        else return selected;
                    }}
                >
                    {/* TODO: Add default value from the array */}
                    {units.map((unit) => (
                        <MenuItem key={unit} value={unit}>{unit}</MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If I put

```
<MenuItem disabled value="">
  <em>Placeholder</em>
</MenuItem>
```

before the map() function, it shows "placeholder" as a disabled option of the menu list but that's not what I need.

I've also tried to set condition like:

```
if (selected.length === 0)
if (selected === '')
```

It looks like when I click on the Select list, I can console log the `selected` value but by default, it's not triggered.

Comment: Are you trying to use Placeholder as a value? Usage based on the doc is as expected, placeholder is not to be deemed as a value rather guiding factor for the user.

Comment: Another tip: don’t use event.target inside your setState. Declare const on outside.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44708518/1253769

Comment: @Rikin No, I just want to have the placeholder there to indicate the type of input, not as a value.

Comment: @NathanHall Thank you. I'll try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the default state units to Placeholder:

```
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    units: 'Placeholder'
  });
```

You can refer to this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7n0bd?fontsize=14) example

---

Update:
The above answer doesn't actually work with multiple select. 
To see code that works with multiple select, check this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rdsg0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thank you @Ido. Your answer is correct for my case so I'll mark it as correct. I'm still a bit confused by the example by the Material UI team.

Comment: Your case do not compatible  with multiple select.

Comment: @ahuigo You are right. Here is a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-rdsg0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that works with multiple select.

Comment: The multiselect example also doesn't work well. If you select one choice the label "placeholder" then moves up to the top of the drop-down, which makes it apply to the drop-down as the label which semantically makes no sense.