# I have got the values in this.state i'm filtering the state , but i'm getting the value is null

Tags: reactjs, search

I'm new to react, i'm working on the search property. I am getting the values from state component when i try to filter it , it's throwing the below error.
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

```
   return (
        <div>
        <Form>

          <Row>
          <Col sm={10}>
          <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" value = {this.state.Searchvalue} onChange = {e => this.setState(prevState => ({ 
          SearchBooks: prevState.SearchBooks.filter(book => book.title === e.target.value)
        }))} />
          </Col>
          <Col sm={2}>
          <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
          </Col>
          </Row>

        </Form>

        <br/>

              {this.state.SearchBooks.map(book => (

                <div>

                    <Card key = {book.id}>
                    <Card.Header as="h5">{book.bookname}</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{book.title}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                        Author : {book.authorname}<br/>
                        Email id : {book.aemailid}<br/>
                        ISBN : {book.isbn}<br/>

                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={ () => this.removeBook(book.id)}>Delete Book</Button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.flagedit(true,book)}>Edit Book</Button>
                    {/* <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.editmodal(book.bookname)}>Edit Book</Button>  */}
                    {this.editmodal()}
                    </Card.Body>
                    <Card.Footer className="text-muted">count : {book.count}</Card.Footer>
                    </Card>
                    <br/>
                </div>

              ))}

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708518/event-target-is-null-inside-functional-setstate

Answer (score 0):

Because of performance concerns, react reuses event object, setting them to null between different events. So at the time your stateUpdated function is executed the value of event is null, and so trying to read null.value will throw "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

To solve it, you can do something like this

```
<FormControl
  type="text"
  placeholder="Search"
  value={this.state.Searchvalue}
  onChange={e => {
    const currentValue = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      SearchBooks: prevState.SearchBooks.filter(
        book => book.title === currentValue
      ),
    }));
  }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are using `e.target.value` inside `setState()`.

Two factors affecting this:

1. Since `onChange` is a [`Synthetic Event`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html), it will be reused after it is invoked. Thus, `e` is **cleared / nullified after `onChange`**
2. `setState()` is async.

Thus, you could either:

**1. Declare a variable**:

```
onChange = (e) => {
  const eventValue = e.target.value // declare a variable

  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    SearchBooks: prevState.SearchBooks.filter(book => book.title === eventValue)
  })
}

<FormControl type="text"
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

or

**2. Persist the event via `event.persist()`**

```
onChange = (e) => {
  e.persist() // persist event

  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    SearchBooks: prevState.SearchBooks.filter(book =>
      book.title === event.target.value
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi Joseph D , thank you for your answer. I tried the first method.If i provide !== operator instead of === it is returning rest of the values. But if i use === it's not matching the value.I'm getting null array.Can you help we with this?

Comment: Hi, take a look at how [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works.